# Tyre pressure ratio

Tags: tires, tire-pressure

I recently got serviced my car that is 40k on it .They changed front left tyre and rest three tyres are still Okay. If normal pressure is 32psi what level should be   for new tyre?   Tyre id (205/55R16)  Feedback appreciated

Comment: why was the tire replaced and why would you think the new one required a different pressure?

Comment: My mechanic recommended to replace it  because  no much  tread left on it And kept it bit low the reason new tyre ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, your spelling of "tire" is killing me.

Second open the drivers side door if this is an American car, or look under the hood need the radiator for a plate which will specify tire pressures recommended for all tires, new or old.

Finally, replacing one tire on an axle is a big no-no. Shame on your mechanic.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307719/what-s-the-difference-between-tire-and-tyre don't die please

Comment: Yeah I know. To each his own. Being the self centered American I am, I had to complain about it.

Comment: I guess I should also say bonnet instead of hood. 

Answer (score 0):

32psi as the pressure is set for the use / load that is applied to the tyre.

Some cars do give a higher figure for fully loaded or for high speed cruising, but I have not seen a figure for "new" tyres - well not for my vehicles : Landrovers, minis, Hillman Imps, Audis, Volvos, Jaguar - a combination of rear wheel, front wheel and four wheel drive.